# Spotify pass Variables + redirect URL

Tags: java, php, spotify

For a bot I'm proramming, I encountered a problem:

**Summary and function**

When a user writes (in a chat-application) !add `spotify:track:someHash`, I'm calling a `java`-function, which then calls a PHP-Script.

FYI: I'm using [this git-project](https://github.com/jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php). I followed the [documentation](http://jwilsson.github.io/spotify-web-api-php/authorization.html) for the authorization-stuff and I can add my tracks, when I hard-coded them in my source.

Let me show you the important snippets:

```
if (spotifyTrack.startsWith("spotify")) {

    // this might be important, maybe need to change this?
    URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/spot/index.php");

    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(con.getOutputStream());
    ps.print("track=" + spotifyTrack);
    con.getInputStream();
    ps.close();
    sendMessage.setText("Song added");
}
```

Lets say, my variable spotifyTrack contains something like this:
`spotify:track:06faVvKZVHivuKgL8NUMQr`

So, I'm calling my **index.php**

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// I'm calling another script here, add.php, you see why down below
$session = new SpotifyWebAPI\Session('My ID','My Secret','http://www.example.com./spot/add.php');
$api = new SpotifyWebAPI\SpotifyWebAPI();

$scopes = array(
    'playlist-read-private',
    'user-read-private',
    'playlist-modify-public'
);

$authorizeUrl = $session->getAuthorizeUrl(array(
    'scope' => $scopes
));

header('Location: ' . $authorizeUrl);
die();   
// Start using the API!
```

This here is the 2nd Script: **add.php**

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$session = new SpotifyWebAPI\Session('My Id', 'MY Secret','http://www.example.com/spot/add.php');
$api = new SpotifyWebAPI\SpotifyWebAPI();

$scopes = array(
    'playlist-read-private',
    'user-read-private',
    'playlist-modify-public'
);

$authorizeUrl = $session->getAuthorizeUrl(array(
    'scope' => $scopes
));

// Request a access token using the code from Spotify
$session->requestAccessToken($_GET['code']);
$accessToken = $session->getAccessToken();

// Set the access token on the API wrapper
$api->setAccessToken($accessToken);

$track = explode(":", $_POST['track']);

// Start using the API!
$api->addUserPlaylistTracks('my user', 'my playlist id', array(
$track[2],
));
```

As you can tell, there is stuff redundant and not the nicest way to do so. However, I'm stuck, since I don't know what to do next. You have to **specify the redirect URI**'s, so I added **index.php** and **add.php**.

The problem: If I'm calling the index.php from my java-programm and change the URL in my index.php to index.php, it'll end in an infinite redirect-loop. 
However, calling the script add.php will result in losing the `POST-data`.

From my understanding: I have to call the index.php, need the redirect to obtain the code-parameter. (Guessing OAuth related?)

My question: How can I keep the POST-data after redirecting (with `header()`) without losing my request?

Answer (score 1):

if you need to carry your data forward to another page you could use sessions:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['post_data'] = $_POST;
```

Answer (score 1):

@cKarsten solutions is in my eyes overhead as the value of `$_POST['track']` is required only once, and this in the page to which is redirected to. Further the data are unnecessarly stored.

I would rather modify `index.php` by passing the value of `$_POST['track']` as get-paramater to `app.php`. Respectively in app.php `$_POST['track']` has to be changed to `$_GET['track']`.

I demonstrate it. Following is unsecure but shows the way I would do it.
The modified code is marked by "// ADDED:" in the previous line.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// I'm calling another script here, add.php, you see why down below
$session = new SpotifyWebAPI\Session('My ID','My   Secret','http://www.example.com./spot/add.php');
$api = new SpotifyWebAPI\SpotifyWebAPI();

$scopes = array(
'playlist-read-private',
'user-read-private',
'playlist-modify-public'
);

$authorizeUrl = $session->getAuthorizeUrl(array(
'scope' => $scopes
));

// ADDED: if $authorizeUrl contains at least one get-paramater use "&". Otherwise "?". In this sample I am using "&".
$authorizeUrl .= "&track=".$_POST['track'];

header('Location: ' . $authorizeUrl);
die();   
// Start using the API!
```

Don't forget to update `add.php`.